# How to efficiently click items with a listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view and in each list item i have for image views and three text view, three of these image view are to act like an image button i.e respond to on click events and so are two of the text view. I have tried using ItemOnClickListeneri mean like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View convertView, int pos,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    bomb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bomb);

    Log.i("Item Clicked", "Item was clicked at pos" + position);

    bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Perform action on click
                        //Run  what ever task neccessary            
        }
    });
}
```

But this has a problem it only responds on the second click. i know it has something to do with the parent and child focus but i haven't been able to get around that.

I also tried using the

> static class `View Holder` except i got the implementation wrong it does not respond at all even after two clicks.

Also am using a custom adapter, i used to do it directly from the `getView` overide method but i found out the hard way that is isn't the best ways to implement what i want to do.

Please i need something that would work for me cause i tried a coupleof thing other than the above mentioned but they have failed.

Get View Codes

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pos = position;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlepost, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.bomb  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bomb);
        holder.bomb.setOnClickListener(bomb_listener);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        holder.bomb.setOnClickListener(bomb_listener);
    }
    return convertView;
}

private OnClickListener bomb_listener = new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("HOMEADAPTER", "BOOMB WAS CLICKED AT POSITON" + pos);
        holder.bomb.setImageResource(R.drawable.redheart);
    }

};

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView reporter;
    TextView shell;
    TextView sheller;

    TextView likesnum;
    TextView favsnum;
    TextView comnum;

    ImageView bomb;
    ImageView star;
    ImageView comment;
}
```

With this new getview implementation i still don't get the exact item i intend to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After complaining about this issue and trying to get a work around it. Personally i think androids API of the list view is terrible and should be improved upon so that it is easy to use and implement. I think its a bad idea to call your listeners in the override `get view` method cause you can't always trust the android system to return to you the exact view in which you are requesting due to performance reasons. I am quoting for the developers of the list view. using the View Holder static class only helps to hold the views and access them faster but it doesn't assist in handling event listeners for specific items view within the list view item and honestly i haven't seen any reasonable solution on the internet or Google developer site.

Okay after two nights of racking my brains and endless testing i finally have a solution.

Using the `setTag`and the `ViewHolder` implementation but only differently, turn your ViewHolder static implementation into a View what i mean is this

```
static class ViewHolder extends View implements OnClickListener {

    public ViewHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    ImageView bomb;

    public void  assignList(){
        if(bomb != null)
        bomb.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public int position = -1;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("HOMEADAPTER", "OUR OWN STUFF");
    }

}
```

Once you have done that in your activity where you implement your `OnItemClickListener` 
all you need to do is get the tag you set like so

```
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```

and thats all baby! you are 90% done the final 10% thing you need to do is what ever you wish to do with your gotten view.

Answer (score 0):

Add the clicklistener code block inside getView() i.e where you create the view,

```
getView(...) {
    if (view == null) {
       viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
       view = ...inflateView code...
       View bomb = view.findViewById(R.id.bomb);
       bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Perform action on click
                        //Run  what ever task neccessary            
        }
       });

       view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that before but for some reason it doesn't get the exact item that is clicked. for for instance i clicked a button in item 4, item 0's button gets clicked. because due to performance reasons the returned convertView may not be the view your expecting.

Comment: What approach are you using in getView? can you paste the getView code

Comment: Keep in mind that ListViews reuse views as much as possible. This is why convertView is not always null. If it is a non-null value, convertView is an instance of one of the the rows already displayed. So if the onClick depends on any variables specific to that image, you will need to set a new on click listener every time, or it will basically be like clicking a different image.

Comment: @Stephen The logic inside onClick needs to handle the state (there are many ways to do this but it is different for applications), I don't believe creating another listener is the best solution.

Comment: @66CLSjY You are entirely correct. I was stating the easiest method of doing so. Admittedly, this was also the first solution that came to mind. Although it would also throw efficiency out the window given enough items.


In either event, this all falls back on the fact that android reuses the view and its associated data as much as possible, and it needs to accounted for in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Views respond to events in a bottom-up fashion. Meaning events start with the child view and are passed up to the parent views. If a view cannot or does not respond to an event, it is passed up the chain. When you first click an image, the image view has no `OnClickListener` associated with it, and therefore cannot respond to the event. On that first click though, you are setting a listener to it. So the next time you click that image, it now has a listener and can respond to the event. This is why it is not responding as expected on the first click. As 66CLSjY suggested, you probably want to override `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` in your list adapter to set the listener when the image is added to the list instead of when you click on it.

In response to your comment on 66's answer, keep in mind that ListViews reuse views as much as possible. So even if convertView is not null, you still need to either set a new OnClickListener to it or account for the reuse in some way or it will basically be like you clicked a different image.

Comment: So first i take out the OnItemClickListener event handler method and concentrate solely on handling my event listeners at the get View override method?